# How can I manage all my social network accounts from a single source?

Tags: social-networking

Like many people, I have accounts on [facebook](http://facebook.com), [twitter](http://twitter.com), [tumblr](http://tumblr.com) and this and that...

I'm looking for the ultimate solution for combining social networking sites.  Something like [Ping.fm](http://ping.fm).  Update in one place and the others get updated automatically.

Is Ping.fm the only solution?  How do you update your various social sites?  How do you keep updated?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with Ping.fm?

Comment: ironic that we want to be on so many different platforms and then lament that they aren't all... on the same platform.

Answer (score 3):

http://friendfeed.com/about/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point of FriendFeed in the first place. Enjoy it while you still can !

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I've heard good things about Friendfeed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but you might want to give [Streamy](http://www.streamy.com) a try.  Here is a TechCrunch [review.](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/05/22/streamy-gets-more-social-instantly-becomes-my-new-start-page/)

Answer (score 0):

To manage all these accounts from just one page.. Yoono is the best app.. You can manage all your social networking accounts from one place..! Check this link for more info : http://www.bukisa.com/articles/261299_manage-all-your-social-networking-from-just-one-place-using-yoono

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, the new Trillian Astra has the ability to add in some social networks in there like Facebook. Not sure about how extensible it is towards [insert social network here], however.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you read news? [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com/) got bought by [Facebook](http://facebook.com/) because it was a compelling solution to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is: http://tarpipe.com/ although the last time I checked I don't think that this supports Google Buzz.